# Littering and garbage collection logic

Tags: java, garbage

```
public String pop()
{ 
    String item = a[--N];
    a[N] = null; // Avoid littering 
    return item;
}
```

In the code above `N` decrements first and then indexes into array `a`. My question is, if item was assigned the value indexed at `N-1` first, why bother making `a[N]` null when there was already nothing there at `a[N]`?

Kindly correct me where I am wrong in my logic in understanding this.

Comment: After `--N`, `N` is the index of the item the function is returning.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, assigning a variable from an array element does not in itself change the contents of the array. The value is copied from `a[N]` to `item`, not moved.

Comment: Why do you think "there was already nothing there"?

Comment: @kaya Nth item would be at index N-1, so what diff a[n] being assigned as null would make was what I was thinking

Answer (score 1):

`N` is now, at that point in the code, the value that used to be `N-1`.

Comment: oh I got it! thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

The code in question:

```
public String pop()
{ 
    String item = a[--N];
    a[N] = null; // Avoid littering 
    return item;
}
```

is equivalent to:

```
public String pop()
{ 
    N = N - 1;
    String item = a[N];
    a[N] = null; // Avoid littering 
    return item;
}
```

After the second line of this method is executed, both `item` and `a[N]` are  references to the same object. By assigning `null` to `a[N]`, you remove one of those references, and because the `item` is created on the stack, it is removed after the method returns. This way the only reference to the object is returned by the method. So if the caller don't assing this reference to some variable (or this reference is assgned, but somehow lost later), then there will be no references to this object anymore, and the GC will have a green light to remove the object from the memory.